# Automatization of port scan proccess

Tags: nmap, ports, automation

I have a task in my company, that I need to scan all open ports from my external range of IP's and I need to create something to do this task every week or month and update the results with the new IP's or ports in the range.

Is there any solution to make scheduled scans on the IP range and put the results in a database or some other place like a file?

To be more specific:

1. Do a scan of my IP range and place the results in some database or file. - OK I did this with nmap with no problems
2. Do this task every week or month and update this database or file with the new IP's or ports and remove the old. - I need to do this in an automatic way

Comment: This sounds like it might fit better on superuser or serverfault? But if you're just trying to set up a scheduled script run, there are plenty of resources available via Google.

Comment: @Den, Are you talking about only ports and IP or even continuous scanning vulnerabilities...? If It's continuous vulnerability scanning there are enough SaaS products available in market to schedule your scan.

Comment: Like @Sayan mentioned, you could use the Shodan API (https://developer.shodan.io/api) to scan for your IP range and it would alert you of all the open ports and also all vulnerabilities found. This would be better than scanning periodically and then analyzing the results later. If you want to just a scheduler to run your scan, you can use AWS Lambda with Scheduled Events or something equivalent in the cloud provider of your choice

Comment: Isn't what you need to do just writing a simple script that run nmap and update your db? And you can schedule the script to run every week in your system.

Comment: This is a relatively simple script that a competent developer could create in a 0-3 days.  In general you're unlikely to find automation that perfectly suits your needs, thus why companies employ developers to write custom software.